# Xamarin iOS designer missing features?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

The article at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/ describes a feature I am not seeing.  Specifically when you have Underconstrained Items, the symbols turn orange, and the orange triangle is supposed to appear (somewhere).  I am not seeing this orange triangle.

[image]

Here is my entire design surface.  No orange triangle when I select an underconstrained element (I have blurred the text, but this is a UITextView).

[image]

I believe I have the latest version of Xamarin installed...

[image]

Is this a missing feature or a bug?  Or do I need to configure something to turn this feature on?

Comment: That underconstrained icon is available on VS4M, looks like a "bug" on VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are opening a xib file. Visual Studio is missing this feature to show the constraints warnings in xib file. However, this feature is available if you open a storyboard file.
[image]

If you would like to see the warnings, you can right click on the xib file and open it with Xcode Interface builder (If you are using Visual Studio for Mac)
[image]

Comment: He is on VS4W and the underconstrained icon is not available (storyboard/xib) and thus no Xcode IB either.